# React : Displaying search results not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm creating a little application of patient management. The project backend was coded in Laravel and working, now remains the frontend with React.

The display of the patients in a table using Axios is completely fine, but when I try to search, it seems to not work. The search code was pasted directly from a solution I stumbled on here with little adjustments.

For clarification, the API of the search when typed manually in the browser is working fine, so I have a problem with React.

**How can I manage to search my table in React using my search API ?**

Component JS:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Container, Dropdown, ListGroup, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from "react-super-responsive-table";

import "./styles.css";

class Patient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      patients: [],
    };
  }

   //Pasted from a solution
  const[patient,SearchData]=useState([]);
   //End pasted 

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("api/patients")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ patients: response.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));


        // Pasted from a solution + This code seems to not work but the API is working
      const Search=(key)=>{
        console.log(key);
        fetch("api/patients/search?q="+key)
        .then((data)=>{
            data.json().then((resp)=>{
                console.warn("resp:",resp)
                SearchData(resp)
            }) 
        })
    
    }
      //End pasted 
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <div className="col-md-4 my-2 my-md-0">
            <div className="input-icon">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(event) => Search(event.target.value)}
              />
              <span>
                <i className="flaticon2-search-1 text-muted" />
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Table className="table table-hover">
            <Thead className="thead-light text-center">
              <Tr>
                <Th>ID</Th>
                <Th>FIRST NAME</Th>
                <Th>LAST NAME</Th>
              </Tr>
            </Thead>

            <Tbody className="text-center">

              {this.state.patients.reverse().map((patient) => (
                <Tr>
                  <Td>
                    {patient.id}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>
                    {patient.firstname}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>
                    {patient.lastname}
                  </Td>
                </Tr>
              ))}

            </Tbody>

          </Table>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Patient;
```

Comment: First thing I see is you're using hooks on a class component. That is something you would never do, so change your state to be set as a hook using useState (as you did with the pasted solution). This on a side, your Search function is inside componentDidMount, which is outside your component scope. Move it outside the componentDidMount instead to make it reachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're defining Search inside ComponentDidMount, which will drop out of scope before the component renders. Try defining it as part of the component, instead.

You may also need to refer to it as `this.Search` inside the render block.

Comment: I see. What you mean by `this.Search` is in the input?

Comment: In your onChange method.